# Zookeeper data directory cleanup

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am running 3 node zookeeper cluster to process storm and kafka.Zookeeper Data directory eats up all the space in my system.I am not sure how to clean it up.As, I don't want to delete the data entirely because i will lose the state of the processes.I looked into `autopurge.purgeInterval` in `zoo.cfg`, but it doesn't work as I expected.

I am using zookeeper 3.4.6

How can I delete the old data without affecting the new ones?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have zookeeper installed in `/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6`, the following will delete all but the last 10 snapshots.

1. stop zookeeper (`/opt/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh stop`)
2. `cd /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6`
3. `./zkCleanup.sh ../data/ -n 10`

Probably wise to make a backup of the whole /opt/zookeeper-3.4.6 dir before doing this.

Comment: Note that you do _not_ need to shutdown zookeeper to cleanup old snapshots. They aren't live data.

Comment: As with 3.4.5 version, the clean command is just: ./bin/zkClean.sh -n 10. The dataLogDir parameter shouldn't be added.

Answer (score 4):

1. Stop Zookeeper
2. Go to the bin folder of your Zookeeper
3. Run `./zkCli.sh`
4. Use `ls /` to check Zookeeper's content
5. Identify what you want to delete with the exact path
6. Delete `/znode` or path of what you want to delete

Comment: Where is " bin folder of Zookeeper"?

Comment: bin folder u'll see after login to docker container like:

docker exec -it <container-id> sh