# Apache Storm : storm-kafka-monitor script throws exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I have set up an Apache Storm cluster locally and submitted a topology as well which is visible in the `Storm UI`. Once everything is up and running I am getting the following exception in `ui.log` file. The error is somewhat related to `storm-kafka-monitor` which is a bash script and I am running this on windows.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

```
2018-06-05 11:26:20.293 o.a.s.u.TopologySpoutLag qtp1185188034-26 [WARN] Exception thrown while getting lag for spout id: kafka-spout and spout class: org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout
2018-06-05 11:26:20.294 o.a.s.u.TopologySpoutLag qtp1185188034-26 [WARN] Exception message:Cannot run program "E:\apache-storm-1.2.1\bin\storm-kafka-monitor": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "E:\apache-storm-1.2.1\bin\storm-kafka-monitor": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellUtils.runCommand(ShellUtils.java:180) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellUtils.run(ShellUtils.java:161) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellUtils$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(ShellUtils.java:371) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellUtils.execCommand(ShellUtils.java:461) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellUtils.execCommand(ShellUtils.java:444) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.TopologySpoutLag.getLagResultForKafka(TopologySpoutLag.java:163) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.TopologySpoutLag.getLagResultForOldKafkaSpout(TopologySpoutLag.java:193) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.TopologySpoutLag.lag(TopologySpoutLag.java:59) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core$topology_lag.invoke(core.clj:805) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core$fn__9586.invoke(core.clj:1165) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$make_route$fn__5979.invoke(core.clj:100) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$if_route$fn__5967.invoke(core.clj:46) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$if_method$fn__5960.invoke(core.clj:31) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routing$fn__5985.invoke(core.clj:113) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at clojure.core$some.invoke(core.clj:2570) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:113) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.compojure.core$routes$fn__5989.invoke(core.clj:118) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.cors$wrap_cors$fn__8894.invoke(cors.clj:149) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.json$wrap_json_params$fn__8841.invoke(json.clj:56) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__6621.invoke(multipart_params.clj:118) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.reload$wrap_reload$fn__7904.invoke(reload.clj:22) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers$requests_middleware$fn__6874.invoke(helpers.clj:52) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core$catch_errors$fn__9761.invoke(core.clj:1428) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.keyword_params$wrap_keyword_params$fn__6541.invoke(keyword_params.clj:35) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.nested_params$wrap_nested_params$fn__6584.invoke(nested_params.clj:84) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.params$wrap_params$fn__6513.invoke(params.clj:64) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.multipart_params$wrap_multipart_params$fn__6621.invoke(multipart_params.clj:118) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.flash$wrap_flash$fn__6836.invoke(flash.clj:35) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.middleware.session$wrap_session$fn__6822.invoke(session.clj:98) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet$make_service_method$fn__6371.invoke(servlet.clj:127) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet$servlet$fn__6375.invoke(servlet.clj:136) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.ring.util.servlet.proxy$javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$ff19274a.service(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:654) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1320) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.logging.filters.AccessLoggingFilter.handle(AccessLoggingFilter.java:47) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.logging.filters.AccessLoggingFilter.doFilter(AccessLoggingFilter.java:39) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers$x_frame_options_filter_handler$fn__6967.invoke(helpers.clj:192) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.ui.helpers.proxy$java.lang.Object$Filter$abec9a8f.doFilter(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:247) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:210) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1291) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:443) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1044) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:369) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:933) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:995) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: I think there is a mismatch with Microsoft OS 32/64-bit version and storm--kafka-monitor 32/64-bit version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637373/2987755

Comment: is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Nope, no workaround, just check whether there is any mismatch with platform compatibility

Comment: But how? The script is a bash file and i am running windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note the script is a bash file. The feature (showing how far behind the log end offset the spout is in Storm UI) doesn't work on Windows currently. It's a little inconvenient, but it shouldn't prevent your topologies from working correctly.

If you want to know how far behind the log end offset the spout is, you can use the kafka-consumer-groups.bat script on one of your Kafka machines instead. If you're using the `storm-kafka-client` spout, the spout lag is also part of the metrics provided by that component.

I'm hoping we can get rid of `storm-kafka-monitor` at some point (it has some other issues https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2600), but until then, if you'd like to try providing Windows compatibility, you'd need to port https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/bin/storm-kafka-monitor to cmd/powershell, and modify https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/4137328b75c06771f84414c3c2113e2d1c757c08/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/utils/TopologySpoutLag.java#L146 so it calls either the Windows or bash script depending on OS.

Comment: Thankyou @stig for your answer. Does it cause any problems on linux?

Comment: and what is better to use `storm-kafka` or `storm-kafka-client`? I am currently using `storm-kafka 1.2.1`. thanks

Comment: It doesn't cause problems on linux, beyond those listed in the issue I linked. `storm-kafka-client` is based on a newer Kafka client library, you should migrate to that one if you can.

Comment: thank you very much :). I have one more thing to ask how can we restart our remote zookeeper instance? I am having connection timeout issues. /Zknodes dir needs to be removed i guess. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking. Consider opening a new question so other people can find it (and so you can elaborate). If you're asking how to reset Zookeeper (delete the contents), look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154147/zookeeper-data-directory-cleanup. This is not reversible!